# Troubled with VBA version difference: version 6 and version 7

Tags: excel, vba, vba6, vba7

I'm new to VBA and use [excel 2010 64bit VBA v6.0 compatible](https://photos.app.goo.gl/vqg65jBkBX1ygDyV6). I pasted [the code](https://vbaa2z.blogspot.com/2019/12/downloading-files-from-internet-vba.html), trying to download files through VBA.

```
Option Explicit
'Tutorial link: https://youtu.be/H4-w6ULc_qs
#If VBA7 Then
   Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
     "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal _
       szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As LongPtr, ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
   Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
     "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal _
       szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
#End If

Sub download_file()
'-----------------------------
'Thanks for downloading the code.
'Please visit our channel for a quick explainer on how to use this code.
'Feel free to update the code as per your need and also share with your friends.
'Download free codes from http://vbaa2z.blogspot.com
'Support our channel: youtube.com/vbaa2z
'Author: L Pamai (vbaa2z.team@gmail.com)
'-----------------------------

Dim downloadStatus As Variant
Dim url As String
Dim destinationFile_local As String

url = [D3]
destinationFile_local = "C:\Users\myUserName\Downloads\" & fileName([D3])

downloadStatus = URLDownloadToFile(0, url, destinationFile_local, 0, 0)

If downloadStatus = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Downloaded Succcessfully!"
    Else
    MsgBox "Download failed"
End If

End Sub

Function fileName(file_fullname) As String

    fileName = Mid(file_fullname, InStrRev(file_fullname, "/") + 1)

End Function
```

However, a pop-up window says it can only run on 64-bit systems as follow:

**Compile error:
The code in this project must be updated for use on 64-bit systems. Please review and update Declare statements and then mark them with the PtrSafe attribute.**

---

My questions are:

1. I do use window and office 64-bit system. Why the window keeps popping up?
2. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee691831(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) resp. [here](/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/gg264421(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and follow the hint the compiler gave to you _Please review and update Declare statements and then mark them with the PtrSafe attribute._

Comment: Second fixed [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/gg264421(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: `a pop-up window says it can only run on 64-bit systems` - no, the popup says you have not updated your code to be compatible with 64-bit systems, so it cannot run there. Which you have not, because you haven't added `PtrSafe` and have not correctly change the parameter types to `LongPtr` *only where needed*.

Comment: Hi @GSerg, now I understand the meaning of the pop-up window. Thank you for the explaination.

Comment: Hi @Storax, I did refer to the MS document as provided by you before I asked the question here. The only problem is that I am not good at English and choose the language to Chinese but it doesn't provide a Chinese version. That's why I am here to see if someone can explain it in a more simple way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error tells you, add the `PtrSafe` keyword to the `VBA7` branch

```
#If VBA7 Then
   Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
     "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal _
       szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr) As Long
#Else
   Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
     "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal _
       szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
#End If
```

You need to add this keyword anywhere you are using `LongPtr`, or `LongLong`.

Here is the MS Documentation on `PtrSafe`

> - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ptrsafe-keyword
>
>   Adding the PtrSafe keyword to a Declare statement only signifies that the Declare statement explicitly targets 64-bits. All data types within the statement that need to store 64-bits (including return values and parameters) must still be modified to hold 64-bit quantities by using either LongLong for 64-bit integrals or LongPtr for pointers and handles.

Comment: @GSerg - yeah I am not familiar with this API call, but I have updated the answer with your suggestion.

Comment: *You need to add this keyword anywhere you are using `LongPtr`* - rather, you need to add this keyword whenever you support VBA7 (which should be always these days). If a function signature happens to not have any `LongPtr`s, it will still require a `PtrSafe`.

Comment: @GSerg - I am reading MS Docs, "Declare statements with the PtrSafe keyword is the recommended syntax. Declare statements that include PtrSafe work correctly in the VBA7 development environment on both 32-bit and 64-bit platforms only after all data types in the Declare statement (parameters and return values) that need to store 64-bit quantities are updated to use LongLong for 64-bit integrals or LongPtr for pointers and handles."

Comment: Correct. *only after all data types in the Declare statement **that need to store 64-bit quantities** are updated*. If the number of such data types is zero, the statement is still valid. All the parameters were updated, all zero of them, so we do apply `PtrSafe`. If there are no `LongPtr` parameters and you don't apply `PtrSafe`, it will not compile on 64-bit.

Comment: @JAlex, thanks for your help. I tried your code, but some of the codes turned red. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @JAlex, thank you. I got it now. Even if it's red, the code can still run.

Comment: @GSerg, many thanks to you and JAlex. Your suggestions are very helpful.